# Tool to analyze counts in REST / JSON?

Tags: json, rest, count

I'm pulling data via REST that returns a large array of records. Is there a good tool that will let me analyze counts by attributes, similar to an Excel pivot table or SQL count query? If not, perhaps this is a good excuse to learn Python...

```
{
"instances": [
    {
        "attributes": {
            "AccountID": 1234,
            "Company": "Acme Corp.",
            ...
```

| Company | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Acme Corp. | 21 |
| BFG, Inc. | 9 |

Comment: this can be accomplished with `jq`   https://jqlang.github.io/jq/

Comment: "Is there a good tool" in what language? Giving what output? At what cost? Even if we allowed library/tool recommendation questions, and we don't, this is pretty vague. Python certainly has good tools for doing this kind of work, but even then what are you actually looking for here? You gave sample output as a table, do you want CSV, HTML, ??? If all you want is the raw data `name: count` then a combination of curl and jq will probably get you there.

Comment: Yes, I was intentionally vague, because I'm flexible. I'm using Postman to run the REST calls now. But in the end, I want to analyze the data with whatever is best/easiest: app, website, writing code, etc.

Comment: It looks like the jq reduce function should work: https://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2019/01/11/jq-reduce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jeremy, I was able to get this working with jq:
jqlang.github.io/jq

I used the reduce function following this example:
blog.differentpla.net/blog/2019/01/11/jq-reduce

My final command was:

```
type cs.json | jq ".instances.[] | {dataset: .attributes.DatasetId, company: .attributes.Company}" | jq  "reduce inputs as $line ({}; $line.company as $company | .[$company] as $current | $line.dataset as $bucket | $current[$bucket] as $count     | { ($bucket): ($count + 1) } as $this     | ($current + $this) as $next     | . + { ($company): ($next) }    )"
```

Which gives a JSON count like this:

```
{
  "Acme Corp": {
    "Dataset A": 462,
    "Dataset B": 1
  },
  "Test Co": {
    "Dataset A": 1,
    "Dataset B": 1
  }
}
```